# Custom loss function in Keras, Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, parameters, loss-function

Let's assume we have the predicted output vector:

```
y_pred = [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

and the real output values:

```
y_true = [0, 1, 0, 0]
```

I want to build the following difference vector y_pred-y_true:

```
y_diff = [1, -1, 0, 1]
```

counts the number of 1s in it and multiplying it by a constant.
This should be the result of my custom loss functions.
The goal is to give more importance to some kind of errors (in this case, I want bigger losses if the predicted value was 0 while the true was 1).

This is my implementation attempt:

```
def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    # if it was 1 and you wrote 0, error is very very big
    y_diff = tf.math.subtract(y_true, y_pred)

    def fn(elem):
        if elem == 1:
            return 10
        elif elem == -1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.map_fn(fn, y_diff))
```

The problem is that in this way my loss function will not be "differentiable". I think this is the reason why I get the error:

```
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

Any idea about how to implement a custom loss function giving bigger (or less) losses according to some conditions, like in the current task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is contradictory. You say you want `y_pred - y_true` but you compute `y_true - y_pred` in the code. Nevertheless you can use the following.

```
def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    # if it was 1 and you wrote 0, error is very very big
    y_diff = y_true - y_pred

    mul_mask = tf.cast(tf.math.equal(y_diff, 1.0), tf.float32)*9.0 + 1
    y_diff = tf.math.sqrt((y_diff * mul_mask)**2)

    return tf.reduce_sum(y_diff)
```

**PS**: I'm hoping you have a good reason behind using this custom loss function. Because you can do the weighing simply using the `class_weights` argument when you do `model.fit()`, thus, there's no need to implement this yourself if you just want weighing per class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Does the class_weights also handle one hot output encoding?

Comment: If you're asking if class_weight argument works when your labels are onehot encoded, yes, it does.